# How to open not main activity when restart my application in android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I made an app worked in background using background service when the user clicked specific button (start button) , the user can stop the application task by restart this application and open it again .. then the user can stop the app by clicking on the stop button.

I use this code snippet to let the app close its UI and return to home screen and before that set the start button on disable mode ...

```
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(intent);
```

Unfortunately, when I open my app again I start from the main activity which is not contains the start button and stop button and when I swipe to the second activity that contains the buttons I find the start button enabled i.e. the previous task of the background service is lost ??!!

could any one provide me by the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you open your app the buttons are enabled by default(excepting those which are disabled from the start).

> So you need to saved this state to retain it's state.
>   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)
>   is how to retain and restore the state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look at Android application lifecycles, when your app goes to the background it will get to the state `onPause()` and later to `onStop()`, what you want is saving your application state for later use, take a look at this thread: [Saving Activity state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android) I think the top answer is what you want to do.

You have to save the status of your button, and then load the status later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharedPreferences to store your wanted activity.
Then check it right after MainActivity start, to decide change to new activity or not

```
//check when start app
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("WantedActivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreferences.contains("SavedActivityName"))
        {
            if(sharedPreferences.getString("SavedActivityName","").equals( "ActivityName"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityName.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}

//save wanted activity


SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("SavedActivityName", "ActivityName");
    editor.commit();
```